# grep between 2 files and perserved empty line of file 1

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a problem with a `grep`.

I have a file called `Uniprot_interactors.txt` containing a list of codes (ex. `GRT986E`) and sometimes between objects there are one or more empty lines.

In some other cases I have an object consisting of 2 parts divided by a low dash (ex. `TRY546 _ TRE578`) and these lines must be considered as if they were empty.

After that I have another file `Good_interactors.txt` containing a list of codes and for everyone a variable (es. `aaaaaa`) is associated. I would like to get an output (`output.txt`) from the `grep` of these files but I want to keep the lines empty as in the first file.

An example:

- file1: `UNIPROT_interactors.txt`

  ```
  QR846OI

  PO3R56
  UJ6Y68


  YU654R

  PL92WS
  GH654Y _ HUY765R
  PIHYUD
  ```
- file 2: `GOOD_Interactors.txt`

  ```
  TYRT68Y aaaaaaaaa
  QR846OI bbbbbbbbb
  FDR59I cccccccc
  PO3R56 ddddddd
  UJ6Y68 eeeeeee
  VFR6y7 fffffff
  PIHYUD gggggggg
  UH7609 hhhhhhhh
  ```
- file `output.txt` (same format of file 1)

  ```
  QR846OI bbbbbbbbb

  PO3R56  ddddddd
  UJ6Y68 eeeeeee


  YU654R

  PL92WS
  GH654Y _ HUY765R
  PIHYUD gggggggg
  ```

I tried to use this code:

```
grep -f Uniprot_interactors.txt GOOD_interactors.txt > output.txt
```

but the format of file 1 is not preserved and empty lines have been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `grep` here as the purpose of `grep` is to extract lines (or in some cases, words) matching a particular regular expression.  The `grep` utility does not modify data, which is what you want to do (add data to lines from one file to another).

---

Using `awk` to save the good interactors in an associative array, `names`, with the Uniprot identifier as the key.  Then outputting these interactors depending on the Uniprot identifier in the first column (while passing on lines with more than one column or with no known good interactor unchanged):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR { names[$1] = $0; next } NF > 1 || !($1 in names) { print; next } { print names[$1] }' GOOD_Interactors.txt UNIPROT_interactors.txt
QR846OI bbbbbbbbb

PO3R56 ddddddd
UJ6Y68 eeeeeee


YU654R

PL92WS
GH654Y _ HUY765R
PIHYUD gggggggg
```

Note that we give both files as input to the `awk` command.  While reading from the first file, only the block with the `FNR==NR` condition will be triggered, while this block would be skipped while reading from the second file.

The special variables `FNR`, `NR` and `NF` are the number of records (lines) read from the *current* file, the number of records read over all, and the number of fields (columns) in the current record, respectively.

Comment: The command works well, only some variables are formed by a string of several words and with this command I can only grep the first word. How can I modify this thing? An example of a variable: "aaaaa rty ity2" and in this case it is taken only "aaaaa"

Comment: @Tommaso See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

loop over file1 reading line if empty echo it else grep corresponding data and print it

```
while read line ; do
    if ((${#line}));then
        grep "${line}" file2
    else
        echo
    fi
done < file1 > output.txt
```

or

```
file2content="$(cat file2)";
while read line ; do
    if ((${#line}));then
        grep "${line}" <<< "${file2content}"
    else
        echo
    fi
done < file1 > output.txt
```